# Where is header and payload information about a calloc stored in heap?

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory, glibc

I want to know how this structure & calloc are allocated in heap. I mean how glibc keep information in memory like this is structure this is its data type so on.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student{
    int rollno;
    char level;

};
int main(){
     struct student *p = calloc(1,sizeof(struct student));
     p->rollno=767;
     p->level='A';
     printf("addr of p is =%p\n",p);
     printf("student_struct_size=%ld\n",sizeof(

}
```

In my system

```
addr of p is =0x555555756260
(gdb) x/16b 0x555555756260
0x555555756260: -1  2   0   0   65  0   0   0
0x555555756268: 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I can understand why 65 is coming but where is 767, also where is header information about calloc (what is boundary of calloc)
If i Do `x/16b 0x555555756260-8` i get 33 , is 33 is size of all payload + header information , can u justify why 33 is coming

```
(gdb) x/16b 0x555555756260-8
0x555555756258: 33  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x555555756260: -1  2   0   0   65  0   0   0
```

Comment: `where is 767` it's `-1 2`

Comment: There are many implementations of malloc, all different. If you want to know specifically about glibc, the source code is available.

Comment: @KamilCuk how 767 becomes -1 2  ? can u explain the process

Comment: `767` is `2FF` in  hex. So.. `0x2` is `2` and `0xFF` can be interpreted as `-1`

Comment: Compile glibc sources with debug information enabled, then debug `malloc` and see how it works.

Comment: @KamilCuk if i have a core dump file is there any command in gdb to know where heap corruption happend in memory

Answer (score 1):

**"Where is 767?"**

Since you are printing the memory in (signed) bytes, and your `int` apparently has 4 bytes in little endian and two's complement, you can calculate this by:

- least significant byte: (signed byte) -1 = (hex) 0xFF
- next significant byte: (signed byte) 2 = (hex) 0x02
- next bytes are both zero
- 4-byte value is 0x000002FF = 767

**"Where is header information?"**

One possible implementation of memory management stores its management data *before* the memory block returned to you.

You might want to look in even lower memory bytes. Expect some pointers there.

To understand the entries, you will need to obtain the sources of your library and to study them. Then you might know what the value 33 represents.

Answer (score 1):

> where is 767,

`-1` and `2` are `767`, little endian. `-1 + 2 * 256 = 0xff + 2 * 256 = 255 + 2*256 = 767`.

> where is header information about calloc

Those 8 bytes with `33` are all `*alloc` needs, there's nothing really more.

> can u justify why 33 is coming

From [glibc/malloc.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L1103):

> ```
> |             Size of chunk, in bytes                     |A|M|P|
> ```

`33` is `0b100001`:

```
100001
   AMP
^^     <-  SIZE
```

Bit `P` is set, which means `P`revious chunk is used.

Bit `M` is not set, which means the region is not `M`map()-ed.

Bit `A` is not set, which means the chunk *is* in the main `A`rea.

The rest is size. `0b100000` is `32` - the allocated chunk has 32 bytes. 8 bytes for a `size_t` number to store that `33` and `malloc_usable_size` will return `32 - 8 = 24`.

Comment: You need to multiply the "2" by 256, not by 255.